# Not able to hit mixpanel in delayed job?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, delayed-job, mixpanel

I am using delayed_job to do some background task. In between I want to track some events. I am using [mixpanel gem](https://github.com/zevarito/mixpanel) to track the events. In controller its working perfectly fine. But not in Delayed Job.

Code I am using

```
@original_message = Message.find(message_id)
@mixpanel= Mixpanel::Tracker.new("43242637426346287482", message_id, true)
@mixpanel.track_event("blank_body", {:reset_result => "sucess" })
//message_id is a unique for every request.
```

I have specified

```
  gem 'mixpanel' in gemfile

              {undefined method `[]=' for 45:Fixnum
```

/Users/mohit/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/mixpanel-0.9.0/lib/mixpanel/tracker.rb:38:in `clear_queue'\n/Users/mohit/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/mixpanel-0.9.0/lib/mixpanel/tracker.rb:13:in`initialize'\n/Users/mohit/projects/textadda/lib/message_job.rb:109:in `new'\n/Users/mohit/projects/textadda/lib/message_job.rb:109:in`perform'\n/Users/mohit/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/delayed_job-2.1.4/lib/delayed/backend/base.rb:87:in `invoke_job'\n/Users/mohit/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/delayed_job-2.1.4/lib/delayed/worker.rb:120:in`run'\n/Users/mohit/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p334/lib/ruby/1.8/timeout.rb:67:in `timeout'\n/Users/mohit/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/delayed_job-2.1.4/lib/delayed/worker.rb:120:in`run'\n/Users/mohit/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p334/lib/ruby/1.8/benchmark.rb:308:in `realtime'\n/Users/mohit/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/delayed_job-2.1.4/lib/delayed/worker.rb:119:in`run'\n/Users/mohit/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/delayed_job-2.1.4/lib/delayed/worker.rb:177:in `reserve_and_run_one_job'\n/Users/mohit/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/delayed_job-2.1.4/lib/delayed/worker.rb:104:in`work_off'\n/Users/mohit/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/delayed_job-2.1.4/lib/delayed/worker.rb:103:in `times'\n/Users/mohit/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/delayed_job-2.1.4/lib/delayed/worker.rb:103:in`work_off'\n/Users/mohit/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/delayed_job-2.1.4/lib/delayed/worker.rb:78:in `start'\n/Users/mohit/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p334/lib/ruby/1.8/benchmark.rb:308:in`realtime'\n/Users/mohit/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/delayed_job-2.1.4/lib/delayed/worker.rb:77:in `start'\n/Users/mohit/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/delayed_job-2.1.4/lib/delayed/worker.rb:74:in`loop'\n/Users/mohit/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/delayed_job-2.1.4/lib/delayed/worker.rb:74:in `start'\n/Users/mohit/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/delayed_job-2.1.4/lib/delayed/tasks.rb:9\n/Users/mohit/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in`call'\n/Users/mohit/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `execute'\n/Users/mohit/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in`each'\n/Users/mohit/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `execute'\n/Users/mohit/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:158:in`invoke_with_call_chain'\n/Users/mohit/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p334/lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb:242:in `synchronize'\n/Users/mohit/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:151:in`invoke_with_call_chain'\n/Users/mohit/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:144:in `invoke'\n/Users/mohit/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:112:in`invoke_task'\n/Users/mohit/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:90:in `top_level'\n/Users/mohit/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:90:in`each'\n/Users/mohit/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:90:in `top_level'\n/Users/mohit/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:129:in`standard_exception_handling'\n/Users/mohit/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:84:in `top_level'\n/Users/mohit/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:62:in`run'\n/Users/mohit/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:129:in `standard_exception_handling'\n/Users/mohit/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:59:in`run'\n/Users/mohit/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/rake-0.9.2/bin/rake:32\n/Users/mohit/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/bin/rake:19:in `load'\n/Users/mohit/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/bin/rake:19

**EDIT**

I have implemented mixpanel in background process using standard get request. But I am still looking for the solution how can I use Mixpanel gem in background process.

Comment: Have you tried `require 'mixpanel'` to explicitly require it before you call it via `Mixpanel::Tracker...`?

Comment: @Seamus Abshere  updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just be doing something like this:

```
@mixpanel= Mixpanel::Tracker.new("43242637426346287482", {:REMOTE_ADDR => message_id}, true)
@mixpanel.track_event("blank_body", {:reset_result => "sucess" })
```

The gem expects the second variable to be the request environment, so will get the ip address that way, and send that to mixpanel.com. But I am not even sure if that is really needed, so I think that even a simple

```
@mixpanel= Mixpanel::Tracker.new("43242637426346287482", {}, true)
@mixpanel.track_event("blank_body", {:reset_result => "sucess" })
```

should work.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

**NOTE: THIS ANSWER IS NOW OUT OF DATE AS OF OCT 15 2012 AS THE INITIALIZE METHOD NO LONGER TAKES A ENV PARAMETER**

The example on https://github.com/zevarito/mixpanel `Mixpanel::Tracker.new` gets called like this:

```
Mixpanel::Tracker.new("YOUR_MIXPANEL_API_TOKEN", request.env, true)
```

In a controller context, `request.env` is a hash.

In your code above your passing in `message_id` as the second argument, which looks like an integer.  Sorry, can't help anymore than that, don't know anything about the mixpanel gem, but that's the root of your problem.

If the mixpanel API documentation tells you you can pass an integer as the second parameter, it's incorrect.  Here's the code relevant to your error from https://github.com/zevarito/mixpanel/blob/master/lib/mixpanel/tracker.rb

```
module Mixpanel
  class Tracker
    def initialize(token, env, async = false)
      @token = token
      @env = env
      @async = async
      clear_queue
    end

# snip

    def clear_queue
      @env["mixpanel_events"] = []
    end

# snip

  end
end
```

Passing an integer as the second argument to the initializer will not work, because the `Fixnum` class doesn't have a hash assignment (`[]=`) method, which is exactly the error message you are getting.

If the documentation tells you this can be an integer, you should probably file an issue against mixpanel.

Comment: IN back ground process you dont have access to request.env and this is should be just a unique code as per mixpanel api..

Comment: I've updated the answer with a bit more detail, where in the API docs does it say this can be an integer?

Comment: From API:-- One thing to keep in mind is that you have to include a unique identifier with the data you send from Ruby, as we are unable to use the request's IP address for uniqueness tracking. You need to include either 'distinct_id' or 'ip' as a property of your request.

Comment: And more over when I sent this query to their support I got this as reply:
The Mixpanel ruby library is community-supported & I haven't used it. Please feel free to update it to work in your environment, it should be quite simple.